# How to use Android constants values as constant names?

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I am using the Place API on Android. As seen in the documentation, for each type of location, [there is a code](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place.html#TYPE_POST_OFFICE):

`public static final int TYPE_RESTAURANT
 Constant Value: 79`

How can I use the String representation directly in my code when comparing?

For example:
`if plc = Place.TYPE_RESTAURANT then showToast();`

I can create a constants list manually, but there should be a better way doing it directly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I added

`import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;`

and then used

`Place.TYPE_RESTAURANT`

to do the comparison.

```
if (plac.getPlace().getPlaceTypes().contains(Place.TYPE_RESTAURANT)) { yourcode here
                                }
```